# Documentation or evaluation instruments used for accreditation of CS programs under The Accreditation Board for Engineering and Technology (ABET)?

Tags: accreditation

I was wondering if there is a repository about the documentation or evaluation instruments that are used for accreditation of CS programs under [The Accreditation Board for Engineering and Technology (ABET)](http://www.abet.org/)? I mean it could be real data or examples on how an accreditation process is made. I know that there is some material on the ABET website, but it is very general. 
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience (Aerospace Engineering), the documentation provided to ABET during the accreditation process was stored in large binders, copies of which ended up on bookshelves in various conference rooms around the department. If you are able to visit an accredited department, you might be able to see them in person there. The CS department at my university is/was not ABET accredited, though the ECE department is. I don't know how either of those department treats their accreditation materials, but the ASE department left them lying all over for anyone off the street to see (more or less).

Comment: Really??? We kept ours in a locked room. Definitely wouldn't give access to just anyone.

Comment: @ff524, it might only have been in the conference room just off the chair's office, in which case, it might as well have been locked. Nevertheless, I saw the binders frequently, and I was not stopped when I opened one and flipped through it (as a student). What's so secret?